# Laravel 5 - Count the number of posts that are assigned to each category in a blog

Tags: php, count, laravel-5

I was wondering what the cleanest way was to count the number of posts that are connected to a category in my blog.

Here is how the table relationship is set up.

What I have is a **hasMany** relationship from the Category to the Post models like this:

In **Categories** Model

```
public function blog_posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Blog_Post', 'category_id');
}
```

And in the **Blog_Post** Model

```
public function blog_categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\BlogCategories', 'category_id');
}
```

In effect all I want to do is be able to return to my view the total number of posts that each category has as shown below.  Where **x** is the number of posts within each category.

cat1 (**x**)
cat2 (**x**)
cat3 (**x**)

It's not hard to count I know however as I only want a count I do not want to also retrieve the records as they are not required and I also do not want to create more queries than is necessary.

I have not completed the view as yet but probably a start would be to pass through the categories in a loop to display each and add the count at the same time?

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {!! $category->name !!} - {!! Count of posts here !!}
@endforeach
```

Hopefully that is clear(ish)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eager load the relation in your controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('blog_posts')->get();

    return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

You can then use the `count()` method on the `blog_posts` relation when looping over categories in your view:

```php
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <li>{{ $category->name }} ({{ $category->blog_posts->count() }})</li>
@endforeach
```

EDIT: Since Laravel 5.3, you can use `withCount()` to load counts of relations, i.e.

```php
$categories = Category::withCount('blog_posts')->get();
```

This will make the count available via a property:

```php
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $blog_posts_count = $category->blog_posts_count;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Martin thanks, on my old world version of this app done in PHP years ago I somehow managed to have this running a ridiculous amount of queries!

Comment: @Holo Most likely the N+1 problem ;)

Comment: Oh absolutely, I have so many bad things in my code from years back that it's making me over analyse everything instead of just trusting I understand Laravel a bit more than I think.

Just ordered your book on Amazon this morning as well :)

Comment: @Holo Really? That’s awesome! Hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: I am sure I will, I will take all the help I can get, and your book seemed ideal for me.  For anyone else reading this, Martins' book is here >> http://www.amazon.co.uk/Laravel-5-Essentials-Martin-Bean/dp/1785283014/ref=sr_1_1_twi_2_pap?ie=UTF8&qid=1431880163&sr=8-1&keywords=martin+bean+laravel

Comment: There is only one problem with this solution - it loads all the data instead of simply calculating and fetching items' count.

Comment: but suppose you need to send the data through the api and the data is huge, how do u get only the count value and store it in each category item without using a for loop or inidividual sql queries for each item

Comment: @BarajaSwargiary Read the Laravel docs. This will append only the blog post count for each category. The counts will be looked up using a single query.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way to do it with eager loading support I know is to create a separate relation with the post count. Check this out:

```
public function blog_posts_count() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Http\Models\Blog_Post', 'category_id')
        ->selectRaw('category_id, count(*) as aggregate')
        ->groupBy('category_id');
}

public function getBlogPostsCountAttribute() {
    if(!array_key_exists('blog_posts_count', $this->relations))
        $this->load('blog_posts_count');

    $related = $this->getRelation('blog_posts_count');
    return $related ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
{{ $category->blog_posts_count }}
```

Comment: Ow, sure! When I wrote this post I took a look at one of my old projects, but I completely forgot where I found a solution it was based on. Here is the url: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/